# how to use the sum method in java

Tags: java

I am reading in a text file with four columns of data to a `HashMap`. I want to sum the value columns. Can I get an example on using the sum method?

Comment: What `sum()` method are you talking about ?

Comment: Can you show what you are putting in the hashmap as keys and values (4 columns into two values) and are what you are summing just numbers?

Comment: @James Black I assume he is asking this question exactly because he wants to know how he can "sum" the value columns into one value.

Comment: @Khilon - But, if he has an array of two values in the value part of the map, then that will be different than if he has one integer. completely different answer.

Comment: @user44... I think you need to clarify a bit more your question. In the current form, is hard to tell what are you looking for.

Comment: @James Black Agreed, but with so little info, any answer is just guesswork. I just have a feeling the talk about sum method is misleading us.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such method like that. There's however the additive operator `+` which can be used on numeric primitives/types like `int` and `Integer`.

Assuming that you've a `Map<String, Integer>`, here's an example:

```
int total = 0;
for (Integer value : map.values()) {
    total = total + value; // Can also be done by total += value;
}
System.out.println(total); // Should print the total.
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)
- [Java tutorial - the Map interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)
- [Java tutorial - the for statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

---

**Update**: I just wanted to add one other hint; your *core* problem might be that you've the numbers in flavor of `String` objects (since you're parsing a text file) and the `+` of course won't sum them up, but just concatenate them. You'd like to convert each number from `String` to `Integer` first. This can be done with [`Integer#valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). E.g.

```
String numberAsString = "10";
Integer numberAsInteger = Integer.valueOf(numberAsString);
// Now put in map and so on.
```

This way you can do basic arithmetic with numbers as intended.

Comment: The key for the hashmap is a unique number. I only want to sum the value column is correct. I'm thinking i need something similiar to code below but having trouble getting it working.              double total = 0.0

while(iter.hasNext()) {
   Propertya p = iter.next();
   total = total + p.getPropertyValue();
}
System.out.println("total = " + total);

Comment: Definitely use the for-each style loop from the answer instead of your iterator.  Just turn the int into a double and you are good to go.

Comment: @user442471 - You should add your answer above to the question, as an update, so you can use the formatting features in the question box.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I made the assumption that you actually need to know how to merge three value columns into one value so you can put it into a map. Here's an example which converts value columns of any type into one string and then puts it into a map. It assumes the first column is the key column and makes no assumptions on their data types.

```
//These are values for each column. column1 to column4.
Object column1 = ...
Object column2 = ...
Object column3 = ...
Object column4 = ...

//This is the map you are reading the values into.
Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<Object, String>();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(column2);
sb.append(column3);
sb.append(column4);

map.put(column1, sb.toString());
```